# if else in php echo (acf true/false condition)

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I need to output a different link based on the ACF true/false field.

This is my code:

```
            $output_map[$the_ID]['map'] = '
                <div class="marker" data-lat="'.$get_google_map['lat'].'" data-lng="'.$get_google_map['lng'].'">
                    <div class="map-wrapper">
                        <div class="map-title">
                            <p><img src="'.$image_url[0].'" alt="'.get_the_title().'"></p>
                            <p class="map-object-title" href="'.get_permalink().'">'.get_the_title().'</p>


IF       <p><a class="map-button" href="'.get_permalink().'">Zum Objekt</a></p>

ELSE     <p>NO LINK</p>




                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>';
```

How could I do a if/else statement within this output? I've already read about ternary operators in a other post, but I don't know how to do this my case..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try these functions `ob_start()` and `ob_get_clean()`. Here is the code:

```
<?php $output_map[$the_ID]['map'] = ''; 
ob_start();
?>
<div class="marker" data-lat="'.$get_google_map['lat'].'" data-lng="'.$get_google_map['lng'].'">
     <div class="map-wrapper">
         <div class="map-title">
             <p><img src="'.$image_url[0].'" alt="'.get_the_title().'"></p>
                <p class="map-object-title" href="'.get_permalink().'">'.get_the_title().'</p>
  <?php if(){?>       
     <p><a class="map-button" href="'.get_permalink().'">Zum Objekt</a></p>
  <?php }else{?>
    <p>NO LINK</p>
  <?php } ?>
     </div>
   </div>
</div>
<?php 
$output_map[$the_ID]['map'] = ob_get_clean();
?>
```

Html code given within these functions can be stored in a variable.

Comment: Thank you so much! Worked like a charme

Answer (score 1):

You didn't specify where ACL is defined so I'll assume it's in `$field['asf']`

then

```
<a class="map-button" href="'. $field['asf'] ? get_permalink() : get_other_link() .'">
```

When `$field['asf']` equals true then `get_permalink()` will be invoked otherwise `get_other_link()` will be invoked

Answer (score 0):

```
$text = '<div class="marker" data-lat="' . $get_google_map['lat'] . '" data-lng="' . $get_google_map['lng'] . '">
    <div class="map-wrapper">
        <div class="map-title">
            <p><img src="' . $image_url[0] . '" alt="' . get_the_title() . '"></p>
            <p class="map-object-title" href="' . get_permalink() . '">' . get_the_title() . '</p>';

IF $text .= '<p><a class="map-button" href="' . get_permalink() . '">Zum Objekt</a></p>';

ELSE $text .= '<p>NO LINK</p>';

$text .= '</div>
    </div>
</div>';

$output_map[$the_ID]['map'] = $text;
```